# JSP Compile Error on Class Constructor

Tags: java, jsp, constructor

I am totally befuddled.   I have a jsp application with a bunch of custom JAVA classes.  Until now, I have been able to do my development in a development environment and then transfer my JAVA classes, JSP files, or my database entries from development to production.  (Two different servers.)

A couple of days ago, all of my JSP files started throwing compilation errors.  I had made a couple of small changes to some units, but not the JSP files.   So I restarted Tomcat and tried again.  I restarted both Apache and Tomcat and tried again.   I copied in the classes from the production server, restarted Tomcat and tried again.   I consistently get errors in the development server.  (I have made no changes to its configuration in months.)

So I have created a simple test application that merely initiates a few classes through their constructors.  It fails in the development environment (with either old or new classes) and works perfectly in the production environment.   It is as if there is something other than the CLASS files (WEB-INF/classes/booknowservices/*.class) that is being used by the compiler in getting the definitions of my units.

For example testing three constructors:

```
 /* --------- constructor definitions from JAVA source -----
 database:  Constructor:
     public BKDataServices (String currentHost)

 utilities:  Constructor: 
      public BKUtil (BKDataServices thisdatabase)

 textservices:    Constructor: 
      public BKTextServices(BKDataServices thisdatabase, BKUtil thisutilities) 
  --------------- */

 BKDataServices  database = new BKDataServices(serverName);
 BKUtil utilities = new BKUtil(database);
 BKTextServices pagetext = new BKTextServices(database,utilities);
```

Yields a compile error

> The constructor BKTextServices(BKDataServices, BKUtil) is undefined

It appears as if the underlying definition of BKUtil may be the culprit - when I try to pass it as a parameter, I also get errors:

```
//  Establish the link between the database class and the utilities class.
database.setUtilities(utilities);   
database.setUtilities((booknowservices.BKUtil)utilities);
```

> The method setUtilities(BKUtil) in the type BKDataServices is not applicable for the arguments (BKUtil)
>   Cannot cast from booknowservices.BKUtil to booknowservices.BKUtil

Since everything works (including the test) in production, I am not totally stopped, but I would like to get the development system back up so I can confidently update the production server.

Any ideas on how to diagnose this will be appreciated.

I have created a CompileTest.jsp that demonstrates the problem.   I have not yet created "empty" classes to share, but I will do so if needed.

Thanks,

DrDave

Comment: On JBoss 4.2 I saw similar problems when renaming deployable artifacts in order not to deploy them any more. Like blah.war to blah.old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an old JAR or class file laying around in your classpath somewhere.

Run your problematic program with the extra VM option `-verbose:class`, e.g.

```
`java -verbose:class Whatever.whatever`
```

This will cause the VM to print out a dump of every class it loads along with the source it loads them from. Particularly, make sure that your `BKDataServices` and `BKUtil` are coming from where you expect.

A less complete alternative is something like this:

```
public static void printResource (Class<?> c) {
    String src;
    ClassLoader cl = c.getClassLoader();
    if (cl != null)
        src = cl.getResource(c.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class").toString();
    else
        src = "[null ClassLoader]";
    System.err.println(c.getName() + " => " + src);
}
```

Then:

```
printResource(booknowServices.BKUtil.class);
printResource(BKDataServices.class);
```

Etc., and that will print the source .class file the classes were loaded from so you can make sure they are what you expect. A null ClassLoader means it's either the bootstrap class loader or a primitive type.

Comment: Thank you Jason C!  You were correct in that I had a stray file - I used puTTy to get to the server and then did a "find / -name BKUtil*" - sure enough, there was a copy of an old version in the Tomcat work directory structure.